# React/React Native: Execution order in a Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components

I am not able to figure out the sequence of code execution in react native. The following code logs `test`, `test 2` and then `test 1`. I want to change value of `submittedURI`.

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            enterURI: ''
        };
    }

    onUriTextChanged(event) {
        this.setState({ enterURI: event.nativeEvent.text });
    }

    onSubmitPress() {
        var submittedURI = this.state.enterURI;
        console.log("test "+submittedURI);

        var url = encodeURIComponent(submittedURI), data = null;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open("GET", "https://api.urlmeta.org/?url=" + url);
        xhr.send(data);
        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
          if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
           // console.log(this.responseText);
            var responseJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            submittedURI = responseJSON.meta.image;  
            console.log("test 1 "+submittedURI); 
          }
        });

        this.props.onURISubmit(submittedURI);
        console.log("test 2 "+submittedURI); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in the `xhr.addEventListner("readystatechange", function() { ... })` is a callback and get's called after the request is `DONE`. Therefore `console.log("test 2 "+submittedURI);` is called before the request is completed.

See the docs here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)

If you want to change `submittedURI` you are going to have to call `this.props.onURISubmit(submittedURI);` function within the `readystatechange` callback. Make sure the callback has the proper context to access `this.props`.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the help. I'm getting `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.onURISubmit')` when I call `this.props.onURISubmit(submittedURI);` inside `readystatechange`.

Comment: Solved it by storing `this` in another variable.